# export metadata for tables only in oracle 11g RAC

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration

I am trying to take export of metadata only for all tables in a schema, like how we take metadata for tablespace

```
expdp scott/password directory=dpdir FULL=Y CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY INCLUDE=TABLESPACE DUMPFILE=tbs.dmp logfile=tbs_test.log
```

Is there anyway to export all tables at time?

Comment: [Database administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) may be the better SE site to use for this question.

Comment: If you only want to export a specific schema, then use the "schemas" parameter, no?  http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php

Comment: I want to take a copy of all tables only for one particular schema(lets say scott). all the tables inside that schema. I know we can use parameter like tables=tab1,tab2 .. etc. But I have some 150 tables in database. If take export of that schema I get meta  data export of everything like tables/tablespaces/indexs,grants etc.

Comment: then set CONTENT=DATA_ONLY

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one schema, remove `FULL=Y` from the command, because that is for exporting all the database.

I believe this should work, let me know afterwards:

```
expdp scott/password directory=dpdir schemas=schema_name CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY DUMPFILE=schema.dmp logfile=schema.log
```

To see each option and what they're used for you can check the official documentation on DataPump for Oracle 11gR2: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, Sorak. I'll pay more attention next time. Rgds.